# How do I get all articles in Video (ordered by id) and all subsections of it?

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables: "sec" and "art".

"sec" is for a section menu and sub-section:

```
id - sid - name
1  - 0   - video
2  - 1   - funny.video
3  - 1   - video.clip
4  - 1   - movies
5  - 0   - MP3
6  - 5   - English.Song
7  - 5   - Russian.Song
```

"art" is for an articles menu for all sections and subsections:

```
id - sid - name ---- ("sid" = "id" of section from "sec" table)
1  - 1   - aaa
2  - 1   - bbb
3  - 2   - ccc
4  - 3   - ddd
5  - 4   - eee
6  - 5   - fff
7  - 7   - ggg
```

How do I get  all articles in Video (ordered by id) and all subsections of it (funny, clip, movies)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to use a subselect for this.

If you only want the chosen and first level subsections, something like this will work (untested).

```
SELECT a.name from art AS a WHERE a.sid IN (SELECT distinct(s2.id) FROM sec AS s LEFT JOIN section AS s2 ON s2.id = s.id OR s2.sid=s.id WHERE s.id=1) ORDER BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
select art.name as ArticleName,sec.name as Subsection from art inner join sec on 
art.sid=sec.id order by art.name,sec.name;
```

You can select other fields as well. I selected only your mentioned ones